# Howto handle typedefs without include headers in headers

Tags: c, include, typedef

As for working on a larger project, I want to throw in some own types (e.g. `myType`). The "rushing in"-approach would be, to put those typedefs into an header (lets say `myType.h`), together with a bunch of functions working on those types.

If I use the new type somewhere, I include `myType.h` to my source-file. Fine.

But if I want to use the new type somewhere as an argument in a function-signature, I need to include the `myType.h` to the header of the module containing the function. With one or another typedef, this seems to be okay for me, but the more types I have, the more includes in headers I need, possible including further header, while using type including other own types. This is resulting in what I call "**dependency hell**".

Is there a clever, stylish, best practice, what-so-ever way to solve this dilemma?

I'm aware of the possibility to pass those types as void-pointer, casting them back inside the function, but then I loose important type-checking from the compiler.

Furher, `extern` is considered worst-practice around here..

**EDIT:**

In detail:

`myType.h`:

```
#include "otherType.h"

typedef struct {
  char Name[32];
  int Size;
  otherType someType;
} myType;

processSomeHow(myType _myType, int NewSize);
```

`otherType.h`

```
#define SOME_CONST 32

typedef struct { [...] } otherType;
```

`someModule.h`:

```
#include "myType.h"

int specialProcessSomeHow(myType _myType);
```

`someModule.c`:

```
int specialProcessSomeHow(myType _myType)
{
  int Size = 64;
  return(processSomeHow(_myType, Size));
}
```

Now I include `otherType.h` indirectly to `someModule.h`, even worse, I include it to every module, that includes `someModule.h`. Now I have a `SOME_CONST` everywhere and it's hard to figure out, from where it comes. I have to maintain two include trees.

Comment: *`external` is considered worst-practice around here* Then maybe `extern` is fine ?

Comment: The problem you are mentioning is a false dilemma. As long as you defensively name your typedefs and surround them with include guards there can never be a "dependency hell".

Comment: Forward declarations + include guards will always help you deal with problems like these :)

Comment: There is no magic solution. Only expose typedefs etc that the caller needs to know about, and that's it. No more detailed answer can be given, as the problem is specific to your particular program design. Program design in general is very qualified work. Even if you have studied a lot of object-orientation practices, it still takes many years of programming experience before you can even do a half-decent program design, let alone a good one.

Comment: So please update the question with a real example, or it is far too broad to answer.

Comment: @cnicutar: Ah, yes.. you see, but not using 'extern' I don't even recall the keyword right. :D But as for include guards, I use them strictly, everywhere, they are not the problem. But I can't entangle, on which way I get those define, functions and other stuff.

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but there is a `typedef` policy in the Linux Kernel coding style documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle). I quote the document : **In general, a pointer, or a struct that has elements that can reasonably
be directly accessed should _never_ be a typedef.**

The policy is explained in details, this quote is only a thumb rule that quite sums up the whole thing. Anyway, you should take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like in the gtk library you can use one headfile and split it on your needs.

```
type.h
- myType.h
-- someType.h
- otherType.h
- List item
```

and on your CONST-Problem:
If you just need it for one c.file. Don't use them in HeaderFile.
And you could name them like "MY_TYPE_SOME_CONST" or "OTHER_TYPE_SOME_CONST";

//EDIT:

to make it clear: just add 'this.h' file and name it.

```
#ifndef TYPE_H_
#define TYPE_H_

#include myType.h
#include someType.h
#include otherType.h

#endif /* TYPE_H_ */
```

now you can use "#include this.h" for each file you need your types.
(this.h is not real, name it to something unique)

Comment: That means, collecting every custom type, struct, enum, #define that is used in several places, into one header-file? How about splitting the header `myType.h` up into two, one containing typedefs, one containing function-prototypes?

Comment: like Roddy say:
"Every .h file should explicitly #include every other .h file it needs in order to compile, and no more."

your myType.h should always have all its functions and it's struct. But you need someType, so you include it. There is nothing wrong about that.

My thought was, that you still can have a "type.h" which only have includes of all your Types.h, no functions, no structs, no defines. so you only have to use "#include type.h" in module if you want to use any of your custom types. If you are using gtk have a look into gtk.h

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably should) use forward declarations for your custom types. See details here: [typedef stuct with forward declaration in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156438/typedef-stuct-with-forward-declaration-in-c)

Your interfaces (the headers) should have incomplete types (i.e. pointers to your custom types) and inside the source code (c files) you should include the `My_Type.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You're worrying unnecessarily : There is no 'dependency hell', precisely because you are giving the compiler all the information it needs to do it's job.

Here's my rules for this:

- Always, always use header guards.
- Every .h file should
  explicitly #include every other .h file it needs in order to compile,
  and *no more*.

So if b.h uses a type from a.h, then b.h must `#include "a.h"`. If `b.c` uses functions from `a.h`, but `b.g` doesn't use types from it, then `b.c` should #include a.h.

- There's no need for `extern` keyword on functions in .h files, because IIRC modern compilers deduce this correctly.
- Using `extern` for global variables may well be frowned on, with good
  reason.
- Cluttering of global namespace. C++ namespaces address this, but in C you have to use naming conventions for all global types, functions and `#defines`. Pick a convention that works for you : I've seen teams successfully use a LETTER-DIGIT-DIGIT prefix for every source file, so `foo.h` might become (for example) `B04_foo.h`, and all functions/types get the same `B04_` prefix. It's a bit crude, but it works. As I say, pick one that works for you.

Comment: I agree with our two rules. But let me show you a typical situation. I refactor legacy code, try to figure out, which include is no longer necessary and delete them. After that, some "magic linking" happens, the include wasn't necessary not because there was no reference, but it is included via includes of includes.

Comment: Ok... But why do you feel that's a problem? The linker will eventually throw out stuff that's not actually needed in the executable.

Comment: It feels.. unclean? And beside, if I want to test such a module, or use it in another context, I maybe use another `myType.h`, a mocked one, not including the included include.

Comment: Unclean, I could live with ;-) But what's the problem with the mocked header? If it doesn't need the included include, surely that's no problem?